# How do I get a button next to a search box in a sticky html container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have adapted some code on a web page to search for text in a table below.

I've created a sticky bar so the search box follows you down the page.

I'm now trying to put a home button next to the search box but the button appears underneath the box and not to the right of it.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the button to appear to the right of the search box?

This is the page code

```css
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

div.stickycontainer {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">

  <div class="stickycontainer" style="vertical-align: middle; top: 0.3em;   padding-left: 80px;">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..." title="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..." class="form-control search-input" data-table="data-list"/>

    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>      

  </div>

</div>
```

Please let me know if I need to post anything else.

Comment: stickycontainer missed an **style="**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to your class `div.stickycontainer`.

If you want to align center you can add `text-align: center;` to the same place and you can remove the `vertical-align: middle;` from your inline css.

Btw, why do you need to have inline CSS and normal CSS ?

```css
div.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 3em;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.stickycontainer {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    top: 0.3em;
    padding-left: 80px;
    
    display: flex;          /* ADDED */
    flex-direction: column; /* ADDED */
    text-align: center;     /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">

  <div class="stickycontainer">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..." title="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..." class="form-control search-input" data-table="data-list"/>

    <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>      

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This still put the button underneath, but it pointed me in the right direction and I tried changing flex-direction: column; to flex-direction: row; and it worked! Thanks for saving my frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You will wrap every element in  because div is block element.

```
<div class="stickycontainer" vertical-align: middle; top: 0.3em; padding-left: 80px;">
    <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..."
            title="Type any course code or keyword and scroll to see all results..."
            class="form-control search-input" data-table="data-list" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the right way... you are adding extra useless `div` that would create div soup...